# Check whether column values are within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's what I have in my dataframe-

```
RecordType    Latitude    Longitude    Name
  L             28.2N        70W       Jon
  L             34.3N        56W       Dan
  L             54.2N        72W       Rachel
```

***Note***: The `dtype` of all the columns is `object`.

Now, in my final dataframe, I only want to include those rows in which the Latitude and Longitude fall in a certain range (say `24 < Latitude < 30` and `79 < Longitude < 87`).

My idea is to `apply` a function to all the values in the `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns to first get `float` values like `28.2`, etc. and then to compare the values to see if they fall into my range. So I wrote the following-

```
def numbers(value):
    return float(value[:-1])

result[u'Latitude'] = result[u'Latitude'].apply(numbers)
result[u'Longitude'] = result[u'Longitude'].apply(numbers)
```

But I get the following warning-

```
Warning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I'm having a hard time understanding this since I'm new to Pandas. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to modify `df`, I would suggest getting rid of the `apply` and vectorising this. One option is using `eval`.

```
u = df.assign(Latitude=df['Latitude'].str[:-1].astype(float))
u['Longitude'] = df['Longitude'].str[:-1].astype(float)

df[u.eval("24 < Latitude < 30 and 79 < Longitude < 87")]
```

---

You have more options using `Series.between`:

```
u = df['Latitude'].str[:-1].astype(float))
v = df['Longitude'].str[:-1].astype(float))

df[u.between(24, 30, inclusive=False) & v.between(79, 87, inclusive=False)]
```

Comment: I liked the `Series.between` option better, works like a charm. Just wanted to ask one more question: there is also a `date` column where I want to only select the rows above a certain year, say `2000`. Is there a command for that?

Comment: @kev Assuming it is a `datetime` column, you can use `df['date'].dt.year > 2000` to get a boolean condition for that.

Comment: Dates are in this format- `20013012`, where is `2001` is the year, `30` the day and `12` the month.

Comment: @kev OK, then try this: `df['date'].astype(str).str[:4] > 2000`

Comment: `lat = df[u'Latitude'].str[:-1].astype(float)`  ... `long = df[u'Longitude'].str[:-1].astype(float)` ... `date = df[u'Date'].str[:4].astype(int)` ...  `result = df[date>2000 & lat.between(24, 30) & long.between(79, 87)]` ...

For some reason, this isn't working.

Comment: @kev Overloaded bitwise operators have higher precedence, so you need extra parentheses: `df[(date>2000) & lat.between(24, 30) & long.between(79, 87)]`

Answer (score 2):

As for why Pandas threw that particular `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice...` warning and how to avoid it:

First, using this syntax should prevent the error message:

`result.loc[:,'Latitude'] = result['Latitude'].apply(numbers)`

Pandas gave you the warning because your `.apply()` function may be attempting to modify a temporary *copy* of `Latitude`/`Longitude` columns in your dataframe. Meaning, the column is copied to a new location in memory before the operation is performed on it. The article you referenced (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) gives examples of why this could potentially cause unexpected problems in certain situations.

Pandas instead recommends that you instead use syntax that will ensure you are modifying a *view* of your dataframe's column with the `.apply()` operation. Doing this will ensure that your dataframe ends up being modified in the manner you expect. The code I wrote above using `.loc` will tell Pandas to access and modify the contents of that column in-place in memory, and this will keep Pandas from throwing the warning that you saw.

Comment: I've written a post about this warning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087).